# Visual Studio Online and Automatic Nuget Package Restore are failing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I have a VS2015 solution with a few projects. When I checked in to VSO, I get a bunch of these error messages:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is ...

Meaning that Nuget is not restoring the packages. Some other posts on SO propose to enable Nuget restore at the solution level, which adds 3 files to the solution and updates the projects.

The issue is that Visual Studio 2015 does not provide this feature anymore, because it now favors the Automatic Nuget Package restore feature. Nuget official documentation is not that clear either. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the automated package restore that adds `nuget.exe` and `nuget.targets` to your solution. It's been deprecated since NuGet 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting the `packages` folder from my project in VSO. Now, when I check in, it can restore the packages properly and build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Allow NuGet to download missing packages" and "Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio" is checked from "Visual Studo\Tools\Options\NuGet Package Manager". And then run following command from "Package Manager Console" to reinstall all NuGet packages:

```
Update-package -reinstall
```